# jQuery Validation with Error Placement

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I'm currently working on login form and trying to develop the functionality I need it to do when the validation does not pass on the client side.

This is the current HTML I have that is rendered before the login form is validated. I'm wanting to place the error after the div class input-group. It is still placing it after the form-control instead.

```
<div class="input-group mb15">
    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Email Address" name="email_address">
</div><!-- input-group -->
<div class="input-group mb15">
    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></i></span>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" name="password">
</div><!-- input-group -->
```

jQuery Validation Process

```
$("#login-form").validate({      
    highlight: function(element) {
        $(element).closest('.input-group').removeClass('has-success').addClass('has-error');
    },
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
        error.appendTo(element.parent('.input-group'));
    }      
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plugin creates and then automatically toggles the error `label`, so don't use `appendTo()` for this.  Also your `append` is appending the `label` *inside* of the `div`, which puts it in the same exact place it would have been originally, just after the `input` element.

Simply keep the default `insertAfter()` and adjust the jQuery selector.

```
errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
    error.insertAfter(element.parent('.input-group'));
}
```

---

If you're seeing any CSS issues, then it's likely related to a failure to implement the `unhighlight` callback function when using `highlight`.

```
$("#login-form").validate({      
    highlight: function(element) {
        $(element).closest('.input-group').removeClass('has-success').addClass('has-error');
    },
    unhighlight: function(element) {
        $(element).closest('.input-group').addClass('has-success').removeClass('has-error');
    },
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
        error.insertAfter(element.parent('.input-group'));
    }      
});
```

Comment: The only issue with this is that it takes away from the default css for the error. Should I just add the css to the end of the line or should I deal with it in another faction.

Comment: @user3732216, not sure what you mean by "take away the default css".  The `errorPlacement` callback only affects _where_ the error element is placed.  The default CSS for the error is still applied on the element and on the message.

Comment: @user3732216, BTW, I see you're using the `highlight` callback function.  Most typically, you would then also need to implement the `unhighlight` callback function to do the exact opposite.

Comment: If I add the the unhighlight and remove the .css('color', '#a94442'). It will not make the message text right.

Comment: @user3732216, You typically would not remove a specific color... just add/remove the class(es) you removed/added with `highlight`.  Did you follow the revised code in my edited answer?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/dw8RXSwF  I did include the line that forces the css with the insertAfter just to show what I'm talking about. If I remove it then it does not change the color of the text.

Comment: @user3732216, You would never put `.css()` within `errorPlacement` and you don't need `success` now that you have `unhighlight`.  See:  http://jsfiddle.net/ph4e8n38/

Comment: @user3732216, to change the text color of the error `label` simply means properly targeting it within your CSS rules.  The default error container is `label` and the default error class is `error`.  Target it with `label.error {color: #a94442;}`  See:  http://jsfiddle.net/ph4e8n38/1/

Comment: Okay that seems to be the confusion on the label.error. It keeps putting it outside of the div for the form input. http://jsfiddle.net/5Lsk1564/1/

Comment: To be eplain what's happening I used the the CSS from my template file and the full HTML to compile a jsfidddle. http://jsfiddle.net/0f5msubu/

Comment: Quote @user3732216, _"It keeps putting it outside of the div for the form input."_ ~ **That is exactly what you asked for in your OP!** :  _"I'm wanting to place the error after the div class input-group."_

Comment: @user3732216, I don't know how else to help you... in your latest jsFiddle, you are causing many of your own problems by ignoring everything I'm saying:  1)  Do NOT use `success` when `unhighlight` is already doing the same thing.  2) Absolutely do NOT put `.css()` inside of the `errorPlacement` function.  3) Do NOT use `appendTo`.  ~ and your last two jsFiddles are broken since they do not have jQuery or the plugin attached.  See my original jsFiddles for how to do that.